# which files are useful to calculate RAM consume by kernel process/thread?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I want to know how we can calculate physical RAM used by kernel process/thread, kernel modules from proc file system?

is there any command or file which gives useful information about this

any one can help.........

Answer (score 0):

The utilities like top/htop shall be helpful in such scenarios by providing the percentage of physical memory(RAM) usage via the field `MEM`. The `RES` field shall give you the amount of consumption of physical RAM in terms of kilobytes.

There is also a tool called `gnome system monitor` that provides process related information, but ensure that your system has sufficient resource as it consumes significant amount of resource.